# Large waffle HowTo

Tags: gluten-free, waffle

So I have pretty successful gluten-free waffles with [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/102383/gluten-free-waffles) but now I'd like to make a fairly large waffle. I don't have a large waffle maker/griddle/iron but I do have a fairly deep frying pan which can go in the oven.

I'm thinking of using the waffle recipe I have but essentially using it in the frying pan, in the oven at minimum 200c. The mixture is quite thick but my concern is that the rising won't take place as it does in the iron/griddle.

Is there any reason that a waffle *needs* to be made in a waffle iron, other than toasting it on both sides and giving it that distinctive square shape and indents?

Comment: If you're just cooking it in a pan, isn't that just a pancake?

Comment: Well, yes, but I want it to rise.

Comment: Pancakes rise plenty @MattW.

Comment: @GdD but Matt is in England, where they don’t.

Comment: I'm in England, and mine do! But then I'm a transplant from the yooessofay.

Comment: Yes, I’m English. We have flat pancakes. My gluten free waffles however rise quite well in the waffle maker. I’m looking to use this idea as a base for something though. Lots of good info here. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I mean, it's still a pancake in the UK, just what we'd call an american pancake

Answer (score 3):

If you use a waffle batter recipe, in a frying pan, in a hot oven, what [you're making is called a Dutch Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_baby_pancake).  I strongly recommend preheating the pan in the oven before adding the batter for maximum rise.

What that will not be is a waffle.  It *might* be good anyway -- you're always taking a chance with gluten-free doughs -- but it seems worth a try, especially if you can do it some time you're not under time pressure.  Generally your Dutch Baby batter has a higher eggs-to-flour ratio, so you might try adding an additional egg to your current waffle batter.